# Where can I find the implementation of truncated normal distribution in the Tensorflow codebase?

Tags: tensorflow, distribution

I want to determine how truncated normal distribution is implemented in the Tensorflow code.

Essentially, I'm looking for the source code for this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.truncated_normal([1])
```

As I work with the debugger, I see low-level functions that may suggest the code is actually in the C++ codebase. [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/parameterized_truncated_normal_op.cc) C++ listing (residing in `tensorflow/core/kernels/parameterized_truncated_normal_op.cc`) seems to contain a truncated normal distribution implementation, but I'm unsure if it's the right one. Please tell me where I can find the actual implementation of this distribution.

Comment: Following the code on github I also end up on that file

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia, than you! The only issue is -- I do not see where C++ `TruncatedNormalFunctor` gets mapped to Python code. When I [search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atensorflow%2Ftensorflow%20TruncatedNormalFunctor&type=code) the code base, this keyword pops up only in three `*.cc` files.

Comment: I would say that you might have better chance to find it if you look for the compiled version when you install it on your pc, because a lot of py files are not listed in the github repo, but are in the installed version